# setText() doesn't work when used in start() with FXML

Tags: javafx

When I'm trying to change or set the text of labels in `start()` method (or earlier) it doesn't seem to work. 
The same goes for other things, eg. setting onAction for a button - it doesn't work when set in `start()`.

If I set those things later in `nextTurn()` method which is activated by button, they do get set.
Setting the labels and `onAction` used to work before I added FXML.

I suspect that the values may get reset to what they are in the FXML. If there is no value in FXML, the labels are empty.

If that is the case (the FXML base values override what is set in `start()` method), where should I set the initial values of labels and other things? Supposed the initial values cannot be just entered directly in FXML as they needto be calculated before displaying the screen.

Below the code (somewhat messy cause I was trying various options):

Core class of te program:

```
public class TheCitadel extends Application {

    GameState gameState = GameInitializer.initializeGame(new GameState());
    PlayerCamp playerCamp = (PlayerCamp) gameState.getCamps().get(0);

    //Labels
    @FXML
    Label monthLabel = new Label();
    @FXML
    Label populationLabel = new Label();
    @FXML
    Label foodLabel = new Label();
    @FXML
    Label tradeGoodsLabel = new Label();
    @FXML
    Label craftsmenLabel = new Label();

    //Buttons
    @FXML
    Button nextTurnButton = new Button("Next turn");
    @FXML
    Button addCreaftsmenButton = new Button("Add Craftsmen");
    @FXML
    Button removeCreaftsmenButton = new Button("Remove Craftsmen");


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {



        //stage and layout
        Stage mainWindow = primaryStage;
        mainWindow.setTitle("The Citadel");
        //GridPane layout = new GridPane();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/view/MainScreen.fxml"));
        Parent layout = loader.load();
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(layout);

        mainWindow.setScene(mainScene);
        mainWindow.show();

        monthLabel = new Label("Month: " + gameState.getTime().getCurrentMonth().toString());
        populationLabel = new Label("Population: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulation()));
        populationLabel.setText ("Population: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulation()));
        foodLabel = new Label("Food: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getFood()));
        tradeGoodsLabel = new Label("Trade goods: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getTradeGoods()));
        craftsmenLabel = new Label("Craftsmen: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulationAsCraftsmen()));

        //buttons
        nextTurnButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                    proceedGameTime();
                    monthLabel.setText(gameState.getTime().getCurrentMonth().toString());
                    populationLabel.setText("Population: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulation()));
                    foodLabel.setText("Food: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getFood()));
                    tradeGoodsLabel.setText("Trade goods: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getTradeGoods()));
                    craftsmenLabel.setText("Craftsmen: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulationAsCraftsmen()));
                }
        );



        addCreaftsmenButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (playerCamp.getPopulation() >= 1) {
                playerCamp.setPopulation(playerCamp.getPopulation() - 1);
                populationLabel.setText("Population: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulation()));
                playerCamp.setPopulationAsCraftsmen(playerCamp.getPopulationAsCraftsmen() + 1);
                craftsmenLabel.setText("Craftsmen: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulationAsCraftsmen()));
            }
        });

        removeCreaftsmenButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (playerCamp.getPopulationAsCraftsmen() >= 1) {
                playerCamp.setPopulation(playerCamp.getPopulation() + 1);
                populationLabel.setText("Population: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulation()));
                playerCamp.setPopulationAsCraftsmen(playerCamp.getPopulationAsCraftsmen() - 1);
                craftsmenLabel.setText("Craftsmen: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulationAsCraftsmen()));
            }
        });

        //set layout

       // layout.getChildren().addAll(nextTurnButton, monthLabel, craftsmenLabel, populationLabel, foodLabel, tradeGoodsLabel, addCreaftsmenButton, removeCreaftsmenButton);
        /*
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        layout.setVgap(5);
        layout.setHgap(5);
        GridPane.setConstraints(textArea, 1, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(nextTurnButton, 1, 2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(monthLabel, 0, 2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(populationLabel, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(foodLabel, 0, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(tradeGoodsLabel, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(addCreaftsmenButton, 2, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(removeCreaftsmenButton, 1, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(craftsmenLabel, 3, 0);
        */

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //TheCitadel citadel = new TheCitadel();
        launch(args);
    }

    @FXML
    public void nextTurn () {
        proceedGameTime();

       //setting labels and button text here works
        monthLabel.setText(gameState.getTime().getCurrentMonth().toString());
        populationLabel.setText("Population: " + 
        String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulation()));
        foodLabel.setText("Food: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getFood()));
        tradeGoodsLabel.setText("Trade goods: " + 
        String.valueOf(playerCamp.getTradeGoods()));
        craftsmenLabel.setText("Craftsmen: " + 
        String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulationAsCraftsmen()));
        addCreaftsmenButton.setText("THIS BUTTON SHOULD HAVE THIS TEXT AND WORK 
        EARLIER!!!");

       //setting onAction here works

        addCreaftsmenButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (playerCamp.getPopulation() >= 1) {
                playerCamp.setPopulation(playerCamp.getPopulation() - 1);
                populationLabel.setText("Population: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulation()));
                playerCamp.setPopulationAsCraftsmen(playerCamp.getPopulationAsCraftsmen() + 1);
                craftsmenLabel.setText("Craftsmen: " + String.valueOf(playerCamp.getPopulationAsCraftsmen()));
            }
        });
    }


    public void proceedGameTime() {
        gameState.getTime().proceedGameTime(1);
    }

}
```

-

FXML:

```xml
<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="335.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.TheCitadel">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="nextTurnButton" onAction="#nextTurn" layoutY="551.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="194.0" text="Next turn" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
      <AnchorPane layoutY="200.0" prefHeight="232.0" prefWidth="335.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
      <TabPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="-17.0" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="400.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label  text="33333333" fx:id="populationLabel" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="9.0" />
                        <Label fx:id="tradeGoodsLabel" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="40.0" />
                        <Label fx:id="foodLabel" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="22.0" />
                         <Button fx:id="addCreaftsmenButton" layoutY="551.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="194.0" text="addCreaftsmenButton" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />

                     </children>
              </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not instantiate Nodes annotated with @FXML, they will be injected by JavaFX and you are reassigning them. Get rid of all the `new Label()` etc.
Also, you should not use the Application class as a controller. Move the Labels, Buttons and Event Handlers to a separate class. Then, in your fxml, put `#onAction=yourEventHandlerMethod`.
JavaFX supports

```
@FXML 
private void initialize()
```

methods in Controllers where you can put initialization logic.